Scaling a web application for large workload
We have SAAS-based application built in CakePHP, MySQL, one module used daily by 10,000 users.
It is hosted on dedicated CPU Linode with 4CPU 8GB-RAM. MySQL is hosted locally as of now.
Occasionally in exams season there is extra load from examination branch to generate result PDFs of each student. So if we say Class I-A have 30 students then it will take 9-10 seconds to generate PDF for them. But data generation takes only 1-2 seconds.
Time is not the big issue they can wait 9-10 seconds for single class but there is issue of server load. Server got loaded due to requests from multiple schools at a time. Due to that request timeout errors occur.
What is the best way to scale the application?
We tried using multiple PHP PDF generators but it is not making much difference.

Look into generating the PDFs via a queue.

It depends entirely on the application; what is the bottleneck, and can it scale horizontally? If the bottleneck is rendering PDFs, and not backend, it should be fairly trivial to spin up a gazillion containers in a cloud solution for instance.

This should be a comment, but space is limited.
You've not told us anything about the architecture. Does this all run on a single host? The major components appear to be

webserver
PHP (what SAPI?)
PDF generator - what is this? Pure PHP? Something else?
Some sort of database (I am guessing here)

Where is the bottleneck? What is the bottleneck (IO, CPU, Memory, network).
Can the components be decoupled? Do you need session support across multiple nodes? Do you have a solution for sessions across multiple nodes?

Due to that request timeout errors occur.

No. There is a chain of causality between high demand and timeouts - they are not the same thing / you need to decompose that.

It is hosted on dedicated CPU Linode with 4CPU 8GB-RAM. MySQL is hosted locally as of now.

5 specific questions: none of which were how much memory does it have: none of which were where is it hosted.
